# Public SQL Connection String using Field Initializer

Tags: c#

I want a public connection string which is populated from textbox text.

```
public static string conString ="server=" + tb_serverinfo.Text + "; database=master;user=" + tb_user.Text + ";pwd=" + tb_password.Text + ";Connection Timeout=5";
```

This won't work due to

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Database_Tool.tb_serverinfo'    The Database Tool   C:\Users...    120 Active

I am new to C# so I can't always work out what I need to do to solve my issue.

Eventually I would like a public SQL Connection so i can just do a `try` statement and `conn.open` anywhere but i'll try and work that out later on.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read up on the difference between static fields and instance fields, basically. I would also recommend against having a public SqlConnection variable - instead, you could have a method which opens a SqlConnection on demand, and then call that from wherever you need to, but close the connection when you're done with that operation.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will read up on that, thanks. That is exactly what I want to do, open and close within a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear.  You are trying to initialize a static (same for all instances) variable from non-static (different for different instances) data.  Sounds like you need a non-static function or property that will build your connection string:

```
public string conString 
{
    get{
        return "server=" 
             + tb_serverinfo.Text 
             + "; database=master;user=" 
             + tb_user.Text 
             + ";pwd=" 
             + tb_password.Text 
             + ";Connection Timeout=5";
    }  
}
```

> Eventually I would like a public SQL Connection ...

Bad idea.  Connections are pooled by .NET, so creating one isn't generally an expensive process. Rather than wasting energy trying to figure out if your "shared" connection is open, setting the connection string, etc.  It's better to just create one when you need it, open it, do your stuff, and dispose of it (which also closes it) when you're done.

An efficient way to do that is with a `using` block:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        ... use the command
    }  // cmd is disposed
}  // conn is disposed
```

That way everything is cleaned up nicely, even if there is an exception.

Comment: Thanks very much!


Would it be possible to have an if statement to determine if it uses these parameters of a connection? I want the user to be able to have a tick box for SQL Authentication / Windows i.e. IF checkbox.ticked = true then use this string, else use another?

Comment: Sure - you could have two different properties, or a function that takes all possible parameters and returns the appropriate string, or something else.  Try something and come back with specific problems.